# Retrofit -Android 11

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I did code for Initialise  retrofit to call web services . it works in all other android version . **I tried to run it on android 11** but getting below error:-

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.reswaiter, PID: 6102
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

and here is my code for retrofit
**below code is not working in android 11**

```
val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(TIMEOUT.toLong(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .readTimeout(TIMEOUT.toLong(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .addInterceptor(logging)
                .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                .build()

            client.connectTimeoutMillis

            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(api_url)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build()
```

Comment: what's retrofit version?

Comment: @MostafaEl-Abady Retrofit version is 2.9.0. 
I added answer at below but not working when targetsdk  is 30

Answer (score 1):

For this solution is **I changed target sdk to 29 from 30** in app.gradle and it's works fine.

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.reswaiter"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

Comment: Hello @UdayNayak I checked with many solutions but works with only this for above mention error.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar error in Retrofit. Updating retrofit to 2.8.1 worked for me.

```
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.8.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.8.1'
```